# Get IndexPath for - UITextView should interact with URL at indexPath

Tags: url, swift3, swift4, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a collection view. Inside the user name will be displayed, along with that if he checked in to a place and friends that are with him. I am using the username as a TextView, and I am assigning URL's for 2 types of text (friends and checkIn). It works as it should with only one problem.

I cannot figure out a way to get the IndexPath when the user taps a link. It will send to the link and triggers the function but I can't get the indexPath. I looked everywhere but no documentation about it. Forever in your debt for a bit of help cos, I've been struggling a lot with this.

This is the function that makes username show the 2 links:

```
  //GET THE INDEX PATH FOR ASSIGNMENT TO THE LINKS ??
    func assignNameFriendsAndCheckIn(name: String, checkIn: String, friends: String, cellName: UITextView) {

        let nameSurname = name
        let checkIn = checkIn
        var string = name
        let friendsString = friends

        string = "\(nameSurname)\(checkIn)\(friendsString)"

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)

        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14), range: (string as NSString).range(of: nameSurname))

        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11), range: (string as NSString).range(of: checkIn))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11), range: (string as NSString).range(of: friendsString))

        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "checkIn", range: (string as NSString).range(of: checkIn))
        cellName.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)]
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "friends", range: (string as NSString).range(of: friendsString))
        cellName.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)]

        cellName.attributedText = attributedString
    }
```

And this is how I catch the links:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

    if URL.absoluteString == "checkIn" {
        print("Check In")
        return true
    } else if URL.absoluteString == "friends" {
        print("Friends")
        return true
    } else {
        print("No Urls set")
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: Same ways as: "How do I know which button is clicked in my UITableView/UICollectionView". There are various solutions. Some are easily adapted if your table is "simple", others are more complex. So don't focus only in the fact that's a `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Can you show me a working example in this particular case? Whenever I click one of the links shouldIntereactwithurl is triggered without sending the indexPath. It is different then a button as i cannot give a sender to calculate location in collectionView. I might be wrong, but this is all I know so far. A bit of help it is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have one section, you can add for instance a tag (corresponding to the row) to the textview and read that tag in the delegate method. That’s when it’s simple.

Comment: @Larme you are genius. I tried before with the tag but got the same problem because I was expecting a pretty solution to get the indexPath from the URL itself. Now, focusing myself on your first comment: "So don't focus only on the fact that's an NSAttributedString" combined with your second one I came up with the fix. You are a star. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion Larme gave me I came up with this, and it works.

In didSelectRow, I am assigning a tap gesture and then I make the NSAttributedString with the links. In the second part, I am retrieving the point of gesture in collectionView and get the indexPath. Now the actions will be assigned. Because the first click will be on the String and not the Label the indexPath will be assigned with a delay. So I am delaying the assignment with DispatchQueue :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    cell.nameSurname.delegate = self

    ................................................

    cell.nameSurname.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.nameSurname.tag = (indexPath.section * 100) + indexPath.item
    let tapName : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapName))
    cell.nameSurname.addGestureRecognizer(tapName)
    tapName.delegate = self

    assignNameLocationAndCheckIn(name: nameSurname, checkIn: checkIn, city: city, date: date, friends: friendsString, cellName: cell.nameSurname, postID: cell.postID)
}
```

This is the function to calculate the indexPath (urlIndexPath is just a varaible):

```
@objc func didTapName(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let pointInCollectionView = sender.location(in: collectionView)
        let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: pointInCollectionView)
        urlIndexPath = indexPath!.item
        print("Name was tapped: \(indexPath!.item) : \(posts[(indexPath?.row)!].postID!)")
    }
```

And finally I am using the indexPath:

```
//MARK: 
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

        if URL.absoluteString == "checkIn" {
            print("Check In")
            checkInText()
            return true
        } else if URL.absoluteString == "friends" {
            print("Friends")
            tagFriends()
            return true
        } else {
            print("No Urls set")
            return false
        }

    }

    //MARK: 
    func checkInText() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            print("Send to: \(self.urlIndexPath)")
        }

    }

    //MARK: 
    func tagFriends() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            print("Send to Friends: \(self.urlIndexPath)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't have used the tapGesture, and just do in `textView(_ textView: shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`: `let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textView.tag - (textView.tag/100), section: textView.tag/100)`